# xlib drawing lines dont appear outside event loop

Tags: c, xlib

i am following an example in a book and i have a drawing function that draws lines. when i place it just before the event loop before XFlush() no lines are drawn but if i place it in the eventloop like below the lines are drawn.

```
while(1)
    {   
        XNextEvent(display, &report);
        if (report.type == Expose)
        {
            draw_lines(win1, gca, 300, 200);
        }
    }
```

can anyone explain to me why this is happening? thanks much. why does it matter whether i place the function in the event loop or not?

Comment: sorry, just to clear things up i remove the event related portion of the event loop when i place draw_lines() outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to have changed in xlib. Look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098678/weird-ass-xlib-bug-xdrawstring-only-works-after-a-sleep) and the others it references.

You can do the draws and flush first, then wait for the expose event with:

```
  /* catch expose events */
  XSelectInput(display, win, ExposureMask);

  /* wait for the expose event */
  XEvent ev;
  XNextEvent(display, &ev);
```